# How to hide an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, class, hide, visibility

i want to hide images with the same class in Javascipt. i have 3 images to hide but i don't know how can i do it. I tried it but did't work:

html

```
<img src="img1.png" class="tool">
<img src="img2.png" class="tool">
<img src="img3.png" class="tool">
```

js

```
const toolHide = document.getElementsByClassName("tool");
for (i=0; i < toolHide.length; i++) {
    if (toolHide.style.visibility  === "visible") {
        toolHide.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

**please help!**

Answer (score 0):

Skip the condition, and just set its visiblity (if that's what you actually want to use), and use `"hidden"` (two "d"s). You also forgot to use your index to access each item in the list.

```
 //   v--- use declarations!
for (let i=0; i < toolHide.length; i++) {
        toolHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

The `.style` property only gives you styles set directly on the element.

---

If you want to actually hide the entire element, and not just make it invisible, then use the `display` property.

```
        toolHide[i].style.display = "none";
```

---

Lastly, I'd rather add a class that has the display/visibility properties that you want.

```
         toolHide[i].classList.add("hidden");
```

Then be sure to define a `.hidden` class in your CSS.

---

Ultimately, I'd rather do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tool")
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add("hidden"));
```